# Salesforce Bulk API Failing Journey Builder Process Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, bulk-api, bulkification, sales-cloud

**For Context:** The Salesforce Org is connected to SFMC via MC Connect.
We are writing Bulk API to perform ETL on Opportunity/Lead/Account Objects in Salesforce.
In Marketing Cloud there are journeys running on Lead and Opportunity Objects using Salesforce Data as Entry Source.

**Issue:** When we activate the journey on Opportunity it automatically created **JBSystem_Opportunity_Process** automation in salesforce. Which interferes with the BULK API Code and it fails. In order to make the code to work we have to pause the automation which make the journey of no use.

Also, The journeys are running fine on other salesforce objects.
It's just the Opportunity Object where it creates the issues. [image]